# Large Result Set Not Loading In ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created an out-of-the-box project (ASP.NET Core 4.6.2) using Entity Framework and added a simple data model (book).  This book has a name, description, and price.  I've added some sample data to my database (SQL Server 2016) to test the speed of the views.  The linq query took less than a second to return 58K records.  Then, the controller immediately passed the result to the view.  The view spun for about 3 minutes, and then timed out and returned a `502.3 Bad Gateway`.

I was under the impression that Core was extremely fast and could handle extremely large data sets (upwards of 2-6M).  If you need a sample of code, here goes:

BooksController.cs:

```
var books = db.Books.ToList();
return View(books);
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestCoreApp.Models.Book>
<h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What possible benefit is there to displaying 58k records in one go?!

Comment: 58K records! How could a user possible absorb that much information on one page. Use a paging mechanism to display just say 20-50 records at a time.

Comment: They can't, but when the original load testers were bragging about the power of ASP.NET Core, they touted that they were returning and rendering 1.6M records in less than 12 seconds.  Now, that could have been on a farm, but I'm not even close to that and I can't get all the records to render. There's no real purpose, just wanted to see if it would do it, and no.

Comment: Well every test depends on the hardware you run it on, if you run this test on a machine with 4gb RAM and a CPU from 10 years ago, it's going to go badly for you. Also, *how* were they rendering? Were they just throwing the values out to the page rather than using Html helpers? (PS Html helpers are not the way to go in Core)

Comment: You mix two completely unrelated issues here. Templating engines (in this case Razor) aren't that good at handing such big datasets inside a template, as it involves high number of allocations. Try returning it as json and you should notice it being much faster. Also most browsers will take forever to render such a big html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system is only as strong as its code allows. Two easy/quick ways to improve response time would be:

1) Make the View asynchronous.

2) Mark the database query as "No Tracking" when no changes will be made to the data from the current View. Adding this flag to a query makes it so the context doesn't track changes to the data. So if you DID make an update, context.SaveChanges() wouldn't save them. And if your view doesn't have any edit capabilities, it should always be there.

Using my own Index view from an app I'm working on now:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool hideDisabledUsers = true) {
    ViewData["hideDisabledUsers"] = hideDisabledUsers;

    var employeeList = _context.Employees
        .OrderBy(e => e.LastName);

    if (hideDisabledUsers)
        employeeList = employeeList.Where(e => e.AccessLevel != AccessType.Disabled);

    return View(await employeeList.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
}
```

Note the changed method signature and return type, and how the LINQ query is built in steps. The query doesn't actually hit the database until the `.ToListAsync()`

Someone else may be able to provide more technical answers on performance, or more ways to make it performant, but using these two methods should show a noticeable improvement to your test.

Comment: You were SPOT-ON correct!  The problem was the rendering in the razor view. Once I changed the view to just spit out `<p>` tags, it rendered the view in less than 2 seconds. I went ahead and added the recommendation that you posted above as well as far as making it asynchronous to be safe.